# Parameter passing and scope of array in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, scope

This problem has been bugging me since forever. I have an array and in the scope of its declaration, I can use the `sizeof` operator to determine the number of elements in it but when I pass it to a function, it interprets as just a pointer to the beginning of the array and the `sizeof` operator just gives me the size of this pointer variable. Like in the following example,

```
#include<iostream>
int count(int a[]){
    return (sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
}
int main(){
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) << " " << count(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is `5 2`. How so I pass an array to the function so that I could determine its size by the use of only the `sizeof` operator and won't have to pass on the extra size as a parameter to this function?

Comment: Consider also `std::array` (you'll need a C++11 compiler).

Comment: If you don't have C++11 you can just use `boost::array`, which is more or less the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template<size_t N>
int count(int (&a)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: thanx Benjamin. can u tell me how to do the same in c.

Comment: @sidharthsharma: No, I cannot.

Comment: @sidharth sharma: cannot be done as you describe in C. Arrays **decay** to a pointer when passed as a function argument (and in many other cases). So you will need to explicitly pass the size.

Comment: Given that each size of the array created a new instantiation of the function you only want to do this with really simple functions. For example begin() and end() functions for arrays are reasonable. Everything else should dispatch to a shared inplementation taking the array bounds as parameters of some kind.

Comment: @sidharth Wait, you asked a question about C++, and you want an answer in C?

Comment: @sidharthsharma This is exactly why writing "C/C++" and confusing the two languages is a bad idea.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can you please provide an example of using this template in C++ as per the requirements of the question? Either there is something wrong here, or I am about to learn something new, useful, and surprising.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Use the OP's example main function, just replace his count function with the function template I provided.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Admittedly the OP's code may be misleading, because his question is not in his code. His question is stated immediately below the code: "How so I pass an array to the function so that I could determine its size by the use of only the sizeof operator and won't have to pass on the extra size as a parameter to this function?" So, can your template be used to get the count of an array passed to a function?

Comment: @MikeNakis: I don't think the OP's code is misleading at all.  He asks about passing an array to *"the"* function, not *"a"* function.  The function he is talking about is the count function.  My count function template replaces his count function.  You pass an array to it.  Not a pointer to the first element in an array, but an array, and it tells you the number of elements.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley He could not possibly be talking about the possibility of passing the extra size as a parameter to the count function, could he? Admittedly, he is a bit "English-challenged", meaning that his text is not worded in the best of ways, but still, I think the most logical interpretation of his text is mine, not yours.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Well, he did say "thanx", without any further clarification except that he wanted to know how to do it in C also.  That implies to me that my function template solved his problem, at least in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. There is no way of passing an array that will make it carry its size information with it. You have to do it yourself. You have to pass the count as an additional parameter.

Comment: This isn't true - see Benjamin's answer

Comment: @awoodland But, this is cheating, isn't it? It only works if the explicitly dimensioned array declaration is in scope. It will not work if I have `int myfunction( int[] a )`.